# Detached entity passed to persist exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

TeamMember:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Constants.TEAM_MEMBER)
@ToString
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class TeamMember extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final String COLUMN_COMPANY_ID_FK = "company_id_fk";

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 413726318355320936L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = COLUMN_COMPANY_ID_FK, referencedColumnName = Constants.ID, nullable = false)
    private Company company;

   // Other columns 

}
```

Company:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Constants.COMPANY)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Company extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6747639319802376867L;

    @Column(name = Company.COLUMN_COMPANY_NAME, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
    // Other columns

}
```

Test code:

```
    @Override
    public Response<Boolean> addTeamMember(Long companyId,
            AddTeamMemberRequest addTeamMemberRequest) {
        try {
            TeamMember teamMember = buildTeamMember(companyId,
                    addTeamMemberRequest);
            teamMemberRepository.save(teamMember);
            return new Response<>(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS, true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Error has occurred while saving team member {}",
                    ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
        }
        return new Response<>(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS, false);
    }
```

```
private TeamMember buildTeamMember(Long companyId, AddTeamMemberRequest addTeamMemberRequest) {
        Company company = companyRepository.findById(companyId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new FeastechException(ResponseStatus.INVALID_REQUEST));
        TeamMember teamMember = new TeamMember();
        teamMember.setCompany(company);
        // Other setters
        return teamMember;
    }
```

The error:
2023-07-06 16:30:23.683 ERROR 28095 --- [           main] c.f.webapp.impl.TeamMemberServiceImpl    : Error has occurred while saving team member org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.feastech.webapp.entities.Company; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.feastech.webapp.entities.Company

I have tried adding cascadeType.MERGE on TeamMember but it didn't work neither did cascadeType.ALL.

Comment: Have you tried performing everything in the same transactional context? The method calling find should be in the same transaction as the save method/call, so that the find method returns a managed Company instance to use in the teamMember company reference. Otherwise, you'll want to ensure you have cascade.merge set on the relationship, and that you force Spring to use JPA entityManager merge (instead of its own Save implementation logic, which will call persist on your new entity).

Comment: I tried using CascadeType.MERGE on the TeamMember but that did not work, I want to avoid using entityManager and rely solely on Hibernate JPA based saves. Any way to go around that?

Comment: Not sure why you'd tag it as JPA if you don't want to use JPA, but try performing the read and save in the same transactional context. They then use the same 'session' (or EntityManager in JPA), so the entity won't be detached.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Done, edited it to remove unnecessary code

Comment: @Chris is is not possible to perform the above actions separately?

Comment: Yes, if you use JPA's merge api ;) As mentioned, this is an issue with Spring implementing 'save' to use JPA's EntityManager persist call when Spring detects a new entity. Persist is required to throw an exception if a new entity references a detached entity - which is what you get. Implement your repository save method to use merge and there isn't an issue

Answer (score 0):

I used `@Transactional` on the `addTeamMember` method so it wrapped the method inside a database transaction.